# Can't see the property of a object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm begining with nodejs.
I have a object and I want to see a property of my object

```
console.log( typeof options )  // object 
console.log("this.optionsCode 2 ",  options ) 
// object = { data : 0, codeName : 'test' }
console.log("this.optionsCode 2 ",  options.codeName )
// undefined
```

I try with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options)  and options[property]..... nothing

```
console.log("option type ",  typeof options )
console.log("option Object.keys(options) ",  Object.keys(options) )
console.log("options ",  options )
console.log(" options.codeName ",  options.codeName )
console.log("JSON.stringify(options) ",  JSON.stringify(options) )                                      console.log("JSON.stringify(options.codeName) ",  JSON.stringify(options.codeName) )
```

the complete result

```
option type  object
option Object.keys(options)  [ 'leagueCaption', 'matchday' ]
options  { leagueCaption:
   { country: 'FR',
     code: '451',
     codeName: 'LEAGUE_2',
     leagueCaption: 'Ligue 2 2017/18' },
  matchday: 32 }
 options.codeName  undefined
JSON.stringify(options)  {"leagueCaption":{"country":"FR","code":"451","codeName":"LEAGUE_2","leagueCaption":"Ligue 2 2017/18"},"matchday":32}
JSON.stringify(options.codeName)  undefined
```

Comment: Are you sure that `codeName` is defined on `options`?

Comment: What do you get if you run `Object.keys(options)`

Comment: Can you show us how you define `options` in a [mcve]?

Comment: is there any asynchronous code involved ?

Comment: I update my post -----

@taki : not i do this in a loop after to resolve my promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access nested property. So use, `options.leagueCaption.codeName`

```js
var options= { leagueCaption:
   { country: 'FR',
     code: '451',
     codeName: 'LEAGUE_2',
     leagueCaption: 'Ligue 2 2017/18' },
  matchday: 32 };
  
  console.log(options.leagueCaption.codeName)
```

Comment: Glad to help. Consider upvoting and accepting it if it resolved your query -:)